# PhpStorm and Symfony 3 - For some bundles the namespace is not found

Tags: php, symfony, namespaces, phpstorm

That the namespace of some of my bundles in Symfony 3 is not recognized in PhpStorm.

It affects:

- my own bundles and
- external bundles (in the vendor-folder), such as the FOM-Rest-Bundle

(see also the attached screenshot)

**What I already tried:**

- Reinstalling the Symfony-Plugin (Now it is installed, but the problem still exists)
- Change directories in `Preferences > Languages & Frameworks > Symfony`
- Under `Preferences > Project: MyProject` I marked the folders (for example the vendor folder) as 'Source' or 'Resource Root'
- Of course, after changing the settings I restarted PhpStorm.

Can anybody help me?

[image: Class AppKernal]

Comment: Which version are you using? I encountered the same problem with the Public Preview. In that case you should file a bug report.

Comment: **PhpStorm 10.0.4** and **Symfony 3.2**

Answer (score 2):

Well... Some problems are solved by themselves.
After googling a while to get this solved and posting the question here, I though:

Let's just get started!!
So I started coding.

After another while the reindex started. And - oh wonder - after that the namespaces were found! What a hustle for nothing.

I just found out that apparently you can restart the index manually in PhpStorm, so in case that anyone steps on this problem, just do:

```
File > Invalidate Caches...
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and if

```
File > Invalidate Caches...
```

doesn't solve your issue, try to disable **.ignore** plug-in.

As you can see on this [link](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-181404#comment=27-2542348&tab=Comments) from jetbrains issues form, this plugin is old and is known to cause bugs with navigation and indexing.

Answer (score 0):

This occurred for me too. It solved by restart IDE for me.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35491837)